# Trying to use classes and define variables in a c++ header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a class and define its variables in the header file. All member's data must be private. I think i got the class working, i just cant seem to get the variables to be defined. 
Here's my code:

```
class myMember
{
public:
    myMember();
private:
    myMember(char name, double height, double weight, int salary);
};

myMember::myMember();
{
    name = "Joe";
    height = 5.10;
    weight = 170;
    salary = 100;
}
```

Comment: So you want `myMember` to have member variables `name`, `height` etc...?

Comment: What is your question? The class definition you've posted contains no data members, so what are you trying to initialize?

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour yup, sorry this is my first time working with classes so idk a lot of the jargon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your class `myMember` to have the member variables you are setting in the constructor then you need to declare it like so:

```
class myMember
{
public:
    myMember();
private:
    std::string name ;
    double height, weight ;
    int salary ;
};
```

Since this is C++ I would use `std::string` for the `name` variable, otherwise I left the types the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the class's fields in the class:

```
class myMember
{
public:
    myMember();
private:
    std::string name;
    double height;
    double weight;
    int salary;
};
```

The private member you've added is a constructor, not a set of fields. If you want to use it as a constructor, make it public, and change the name to a string.

```
public:
    myMember( std::string name, double height, double weight, int salary);
```